# Silent mode on Android 7

Tags: android, android-source, android-7.0-nougat

Is there any way to set ringer mode to silent on android 7

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    amanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
}
```

setRingerMode works on Android 6 and lower versions.
From doc:

> "From N onward, ringer mode adjustments that would toggle Do Not
>   Disturb are not allowed unless the app has been granted Do Not Disturb
>   Access."

Is there any way to achieve this without opening "Do Not Disturb access settings" via intent such being system app or allow when building platform code like this app has do not disturb permission etc?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my gist to help you with the problem

I wanted to switch the phone between silent and normal modes using AudioManager but it did not work on android N and above. More details in the comments. NOTE: I'm a beginner myself so this is by no means an expert level code. I'm sharing it because I found very little help on for this.

```
    package com.junaidaziz.keepitsilent;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.*;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


/*
 * Created by junaidaziz on 11/13/17.
 */

public class ToggleSoundMode extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {

    Context context;
    static AudioManager audio;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        Log.d("BroadCast: ", " Recieved");

        toggleSoundMode();

//        Intent background = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
//        context.startService(background);
    }

    public void toggleSoundMode(){
        Log.d("BroadCast: ", "toggleSoundMode");

        //if the OS version is lower than Nougat
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            handleAudioManager();
        }

        //if the OS version is Nougat or above
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){

            //first we need to get the current Notification Interruption Filter
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            int currentMode = notificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter();

            //Just for debugging
            Log.d("BroadCast: ", "currentmode " + currentMode);
            Log.d("BroadCast: ", "case 1: " + NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALARMS);
            Log.d("BroadCast: ", "case 2: " + NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
            Log.d("BroadCast: ", "case 3: " + NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
            Log.d("BroadCast: ", "case 4: " + NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY);
            Log.d("BroadCast: ", "case 5: " + NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_UNKNOWN);

            //Make the change to the notification Interruption filter First....then change the Audio Settings
            switch (currentMode){
                case NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL: {
                    notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);  //Toggle On the Do not disturb Mode
                    break;
                }
                case NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_UNKNOWN: {
                    notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);  //Toggle the normal mode
                    handleRingVolume(); //With the normal interruption filter tuned on, we only need to handle the volumes.
                    break;
                }
                case NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALARMS: {
                    notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
                    handleRingVolume();
                    break;
                }
                case NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE: {
                    notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
                    handleRingVolume();
                    break;
                }
                case NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY: {
                    notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
                    handleRingVolume();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void handleAudioManager(){

        //This part of code is pretty self explanatory.

        int currentMode = audio.getRingerMode();

        Log.d("BroadCast: ", "currentmode " + currentMode);
        Log.d("BroadCast: ", "case 1: " + AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        Log.d("BroadCast: ", "case 2: " + AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);

        switch (currentMode) {
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL: {
                audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
                Log.d("BroadCast: ", "case: RINGER MODE NORMAL");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Vibration Activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE: {
                Log.d("BroadCast: ", "case; RINGER MODE VIBRATE");
                audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                handleRingVolume();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Normal mode Activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT: {
                Log.d("BroadCast: ", "case; RINGER MODE SILENT");
                audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                handleRingVolume();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Normal mode Activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void handleRingVolume(){
        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING), 0);
        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION), 0);
        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM), 0);
        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM), 0);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Max volume", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }}
```

After reading through many resources and testing different ways, I concluded that on Android Nougat and above, the Notification Manager's Do Not Disturb Mode somehow overrides everything related to Audio and notification.

So if the phone is in Do Not Disturb mode, you cannot change the sound settings or make any change that would violate the Do Not Disturb mode. So if you want to put the phone back into the ringing mode, you would first need to change the Notification InterruptionFiler. once that's changed, then you can change the volume settings as well. This is also demonstrated by the fact that if Do Not Disturb mode is turned on, Android will not let you change the Volume on the phone even using the physical volume buttons.

To get this code working, you'd need to have the following two permissions as well.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>`

Comment: Hi Junaid even i am trying the same thing but during incoming call , i want to turn on the sound of ringer but its doesn't ring at all. In the UI it increases the volume as well as remove the icon of dnd but actual sound is not produced. Have you came across any such situation ?

Comment: Based on what you're describing it, I can guess it's a timing issue that I faced as well. Basically in my experience, the Phone call comes in, triggers the broadcast listener and turns on the sound...however the incoming call is still somehow registered on the silent channel....I have no idea how that works but that is how I experienced it...The next incoming call should have the sound. I didn't have to handle this issue as I needed the sound on the next incoming call...So I don't have any solid solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

add this permission in manifest

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
```

and use this code to pop up notification policy access grand

```
NotificationManager notificationManager =
(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
    && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.Settings
                        .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```